# GPU Support of Tensorflow on Linux Mint/Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, tensorflow, ubuntu-14.04, gpu

So I installed tensorflow and the CPU Version works fine but I can't seem to get the GPU to work.
I installed Cuda by downloading the .deb from Nvidia.
I copied the cudNN content

```
cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
#define CUDNN_MAJOR      6
#define CUDNN_MINOR      0
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 20
--
#define CUDNN_VERSION    (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 + CUDNN_MINOR * 100 +     CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL)

#include "driver_types.h"
```

I entered the path in ~/.profile

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export CUDA_ROOT=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_ROOT/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_ROOT/lib64
```

Oh and Nvidia-smi shows:

```
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.39                 Driver Version: 375.39                                            |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:01:00.0      On |                  N/A |
| 10%   54C    P0    42W / 200W |    591MiB /  8105MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1368    G   /usr/bin/X                                     344MiB |
|    0      3078    G   cinnamon                                       129MiB |
|    0      6549    G   /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox                  20MiB |
|    0     15491    G   ...bleH2AndQuicRequests/Enabled/*NetworkTime    96MiB |
```

Yet still using Tensorflow I get:

```
>>> python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
Device mapping: no known devices.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:257] Device mapping:
```

I hope you can tell me what else I can do.
Best regards and thanks in advance

Comment: are you running tf in the virtualbox ?

Comment: no, I just opened it. It's running a windows for other purposes :D

Comment: How did you install TF? Source/pip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you've installed is just a simple (CPU) version of tensorflow. You have to install the *gpu version of tensorflow*. The easiest way to do this is using the anaconda distribution of Python & tensorflow.

```
kmario23 ❯ conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu                         
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment /home/kmario23/anaconda3:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-env-2.6.0            |                0          502 B  anaconda
    cudatoolkit-7.5            |                0       217.2 MB  anaconda
    cudnn-5.1                  |                0        77.2 MB  anaconda
    tensorflow-gpu-1.0.1       |           py35_4        77.4 MB  anaconda
    conda-4.3.16               |           py35_0         510 KB  anaconda
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       372.4 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    cudatoolkit:    7.5-0         anaconda   
    cudnn:          5.1-0         anaconda   
    tensorflow-gpu: 1.0.1-py35_4  anaconda   

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:          4.2.13-py35_0 conda-forge --> 4.3.16-py35_0 anaconda

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Go ahead and install it, right away.

---

Also, have a look that a simple package search would list a separate tensorflow version for GPU.

```
kmario23 ❯ anaconda search -t conda tensorflow                                                                                                          
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms      
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
     HCC/tensorflow            |    1.0.0 | conda           | linux-64       
     HCC/tensorflow-cpucompat  |    1.0.0 | conda           | linux-64       
     HCC/tensorflow-fma        |    1.0.0 | conda           | linux-64       
     SentientPrime/tensorflow  |    0.6.0 | conda           | osx-64         
                                          : TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
     acellera/tensorflow-cuda  |   0.12.1 | conda           | linux-64       
     anaconda/tensorflow       |    1.0.1 | conda           | linux-64       
     anaconda/tensorflow-gpu   |    1.0.1 | conda           | linux-64       
     conda-forge/tensorflow    |    1.0.0 | conda           | linux-64, win-64, osx-64
                                          : TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
```

I would recommend installing the `tensorflow-gpu` from the anaconda channel `anaconda/tensorflow-gpu`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Although I installed the GPU Version with pip. I marked your answer, but I can't yet upvote it. Will do that asap